# How to solve: "exception was thrown by the target of invocation" C#

Tags: c#, .net, exception

C#

Every time I run my porgram I get this exception:
[image]

But when I run in debug mode, there is no exception and the program works fine, what can I do?

**NOTE:** I do not use *invoke()* anywhere in the project

**EDIT:** Okay, here is the code found in the details:
If someone know how to use protoBuff, and know this problem....

```
    ************** Exception Text **************
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> ProtoBuf.ProtoException: Incorrect wire-type deserializing TimeSpan
   at ProtoBuf.ProtoBcl.ProtoTimeSpan.DeserializeTicks(SerializationContext context) in c:\protobuf-net_fixed\trunk\protobuf-net\ProtoBcl\ProtoTimeSpan.cs:line 80
   at ProtoBuf.ProtoBcl.ProtoTimeSpan.DeserializeDateTime(SerializationContext context) in c:\protobuf-net_fixed\trunk\protobuf-net\ProtoBcl\ProtoTimeSpan.cs:line 41
   at ProtoBuf.Property.PropertyDateTimeString`1.DeserializeImpl(TSource source, SerializationContext context) in c:\protobuf-net_fixed\trunk\protobuf-net\Property\PropertyDateTimeString.cs:line 32
   at ProtoBuf.Property.Property`2.Deserialize(TSource source, SerializationContext context) in c:\protobuf-net_fixed\trunk\protobuf-net\Property\Property.cs:line 150
   at ProtoBuf.Serializer`1.Deserialize[TCreation](T& instance, SerializationContext context) in c:\protobuf-net_fixed\trunk\protobuf-net\SerializerT.cs:line 568
   at ProtoBuf.Serializer`1.DeserializeChecked[TCreation](T& instance, SerializationContext source) in c:\protobuf-net_fixed\trunk\protobuf-net\SerializerT.cs:line 400
   at ProtoBuf.SerializerItemProxy`2.Deserialize(TActualClass& instance, SerializationContext source) in c:\protobuf-net_fixed\trunk\protobuf-net\SerializerProxy.cs:line 86
   at ProtoBuf.Serializer.Deserialize[T](SerializationContext source) in c:\protobuf-net_fixed\trunk\protobuf-net\Serializer.cs:line 302
   at ProtoBuf.Serializer.Deserialize[T](Stream source) in c:\protobuf-net_fixed\trunk\protobuf-net\Serializer.cs:line 289
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle._InvokeMethodFast(IRuntimeMethodInfo method, Object target, Object[] arguments, SignatureStruct& sig, MethodAttributes methodAttributes, RuntimeType typeOwner)
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethodFast(IRuntimeMethodInfo method, Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, MethodAttributes methodAttributes, RuntimeType typeOwner)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture, Boolean skipVisibilityChecks)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at ProtoBuf.Serializer.NonGeneric.Deserialize(Type type, Stream source) in c:\protobuf-net_fixed\trunk\protobuf-net\NonGeneric.cs:line 154
   at ProtoBuf.Serializer.NonGeneric.TryDeserializeWithLengthPrefix(Stream source, PrefixStyle style, Getter`2 typeReader, Object& item) in c:\protobuf-net_fixed\trunk\protobuf-net\NonGeneric.cs:line 128
   at AccessPoint.MainForm.getEventsList() in C:\Users\user\Desktop\accesspoint\AccessPoint\AccessPoint\MainForm.cs:line 97
   at AccessPoint.MainForm.Form1_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Users\user\Desktop\accesspoint\AccessPoint\AccessPoint\MainForm.cs:line 18
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnLoad(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnCreateControl()
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl(Boolean fIgnoreVisible)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl()
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmShowWindow(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.WmShowWindow(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
```

Row 97:

```
int startIndex = count - 10, index = 0;
                object obj;
                while (Serializer.NonGeneric.TryDeserializeWithLengthPrefix(file, PrefixStyle.Base128, tag =>
                {
                    return index++ >= startIndex ? typeof(EventsWireFrame) : null;
                }, out obj))
                {
                    EventsWireFrame evt = (EventsWireFrame)obj;
                    AddEventToTable(evt.eventDate, evt.eventType, evt.eventKeyNumber, evt.eventKeyName, evt.eventDoor, true);

                }
```

I can't get it, what's wrong? Do I need to add another part of code? Maybe the seraliztaion?

Comment: Start by clicking Details and take a look at the full exception and stack trace.

Comment: Do what Michael said. What is the actual error?

Comment: I added the code, if you want the full, just tell me.

Comment: Maybe a file that exists in the bin\Debug folder but not in the bin\Release folder.

Comment: It should exist in both?

Answer (score 44):

[TargetInvocationException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.targetinvocationexception.aspx) masks the real exception by telling you that it crashed during "a method invocation", usually through `something.Invoke`.

What you have to do is look at the [InnerException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.exception.innerexception.aspx) property of the exception object (the [TargetInvocationException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.targetinvocationexception.aspx) object), this will give you the actual exception that was thrown, with a more useful stack trace.

Comment: inner exception had all the details i needed to solve this for me, it was indeed an `Invalid Cast Exception` in my case.

Comment: Yeah but `InnerException` is missing line numbers (where exactly exception was thrown), why? I Invoke method from loaded assembly, assembly was built in debug mode.

Answer (score 4):

You are using `Protobuf` to deserialize something it doesn't understand. Probably data serialized using another version of your assembly or data not serialized by you in the first place. Google Protocol Buffers can be used to write a representation of your object to a stream. You can later deserialize the stream to recreate the object. However, it is important that you serialize and deserialize the object in the same way. If you just feed garbage into the deserialization you will get weird exceptions thrown.

The problem occurs at MainForm.cs, line 97.

If you only get the error when you run in release mode then perhaps the file you are trying to deserialize is located in the binary directory and the release mode file is out of date, that is, it contains serialized data of an older version of the data you are serializing.

Comment: Ok I added a section in the main post that is a comment to you

Answer (score 0):

In My case i was using MD5 cryptography where as [FIPS was enabled on server](http://www.asptricks.net/2015/10/solution-exception-has-been-thrown-by.html).
I used SHA1 to calculate hash and its worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

For me, had some null references in the OnLoad() of a XAML project (and it threw OP's nebulous error). Just as Lasse Vågsæther Karlsen answered, looking at the inner exception's stacktrace got me to the line number.

Answer (score 0):

I uninstalled `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore` in NuGet and installed a lower version. That worked for me.