# Implement "GcmClient.Register(this, Constants.SenderID);" in non activity class

Tags: xamarin.android, google-cloud-messaging, android-notifications, gsm, azure-notificationhub

I am trying to implement receive/push azure notification with google cloud messaging in Android Xamarin project 
I have followed  ["Get started with Notification Hubs with Xamarin for Android"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/notification-hubs/xamarin-notification-hubs-push-notifications-android-gcm) article and everything went fine and I can receive notification!

in this article we add these lines of code in MainActivity class

```
GcmClient.CheckDevice(this); 
GcmClient.CheckManifest(this);
GcmClient.Register(this, Constants.SenderID);
```

but we are going for some reason not use activity class, and I need to apply mentioned codes in none activity class , 
as the input "this" for above codes are "Android.Content.context"
,I tried to get  Android.Content.context and send as parameter to CheckDevice and CheckManifest method

```
var _this = Android.App.Application.Context;
GcmClient.CheckDevice(_this);
GcmClient.CheckManifest(_this);
```

but i get following Error in "GcmClient.CheckManifest(_this);" line

[image]

I am quite new in this area but I guess i missing to add some info in manifest file, I really appreciate if you help me how we implement  mentioned codes about GcmClient in non activity class in order to implement notification

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As stated in this [forum](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/11427/system-reflection-targetinvocationexception-exception-has-been-thrown-by-the-target-of-an-invocatio), it is thrown by `System.Reflection` when the latter catches an exception, while attempting to query / manipulate / invoke one of the member of the instance reflected upon. Also based from this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3838680/5832311), *"[TargetInvocationException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.targetinvocationexception.aspx) masks the real exception by telling you that it crashed during "a method invocation", usually through `something.Invoke`. What you have to do is look at the [InnerException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.exception.innerexception.aspx) property of the exception object (the [TargetInvocationException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.targetinvocationexception.aspx) object), this will give you the actual exception that was thrown, with a more useful stack trace."*