# Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. (REDIS Cache)

Tags: sql-server, redis, reportviewer

I'm trying to resolve an issue we have specific to using REDIS cache on our web apps but need help understanding the stacktrace.

We intermittently get `Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation` logged in our error table when users are viewing the report viewer, but there are no signs client side that anything has gone wrong.

I've had a read through this article: [How to solve: "exception was thrown by the target of invocation" C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3838610/how-to-solve-exception-was-thrown-by-the-target-of-invocation-c-sharp) however it doesn't seem to cover our specific issue.

The stacktrace logged by our logger;

```
    at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.SerializationInvoke(IRuntimeMethodInfo method, Object target, SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext& context)     
    at System.Runtime.Serialization.ObjectManager.CompleteISerializableObject(Object obj, SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)     
    at System.Runtime.Serialization.ObjectManager.FixupSpecialObject(ObjectHolder holder)     
    at System.Runtime.Serialization.ObjectManager.DoFixups()     
    at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectReader.Deserialize(HeaderHandler handler, __BinaryParser serParser, Boolean fCheck, Boolean isCrossAppDomain, IMethodCallMessage methodCallMessage)     
    at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter.Deserialize(Stream serializationStream, HeaderHandler handler, Boolean fCheck, Boolean isCrossAppDomain, IMethodCallMessage methodCallMessage)     
    at Microsoft.Web.Redis.BinarySerializer.Deserialize(Byte[] data) in D:\BuildAgent\work\f55792526e6d9089\src\Shared\BinarySerializer.cs:line 37     
    at Microsoft.Web.Redis.ChangeTrackingSessionStateItemCollection.GetData(String normalizedName) in D:\BuildAgent\work\f55792526e6d9089\src\Shared\ChangeTrackingSessionStateItemCollection.cs:line 156     
    at Microsoft.Web.Redis.ChangeTrackingSessionStateItemCollection.get_Item(String name) in D:\BuildAgent\work\f55792526e6d9089\src\Shared\ChangeTrackingSessionStateItemCollection.cs:line 141     
    at System.Web.SessionState.HttpSessionStateContainer.get_Item(String name)     
    at Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ViewerDataOperation..ctor()     
    at Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler.GetHandler(String operationType)     
    at Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)     
    at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()     
    at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks to be an issue during Deserialization. Could the class definition have changed between when it was serialized and when it is being deserialized?

Comment: I'm not sure, would that be a specific issue with the redis cache then?