# Xamarin.Forms command binding TargetInvocationException

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I am coding a Xamarin PCL app but I keep getting this error

> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.

And sometimes

> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: < Timeout exceeded getting exception details >

It only occurs when I tap the image binded to the OptionClick line in the XAML and in C# is `new Command((sender) => ShowOptionActions(message.Id, message.Sender_Id, sender))` I tried changing it to DisplayAlert instead of the method, but anything I put made the error appear when I clicked it.

It also only appeared on Android, it works fine on iOS. They both use the same code.

My ObjectMessage class is

```
public class MessageObject : INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    private int Id = -1;
    private Command optionCommandValue;
    private string bodyValue = String.Empty;
    private Color bodyColorValue = Color.Black;
    private string likeImageSource = String.Empty;
    private Command likeCommandValue;
    private string timestampValue = String.Empty;
    private Boolean showBannersValue = true;

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    private MessageObject(int id, Command optionCommand, string body, string likeImage, Command likeCommand, string timestamp)
    {
        Id = id;
        optionCommandValue = optionCommand;
        bodyValue = body;
        bodyColorValue = Color.Black;
        likeImageSource = likeImage;
        likeCommandValue = likeCommand;
        timestampValue = timestamp;
        showBannersValue = true;
    }

    public static MessageObject CreateMessage(int id, Command optionCommand, string body, string likeImage, Command likeCommand, string timestamp)
    {
        return new MessageObject(id, optionCommand, body, likeImage, likeCommand, timestamp);
    }

    public int ID
    {
        get
        {
            return this.Id;
        }
    }

    public Command OptionClick
    {
        get
        {
            return this.optionCommandValue;
        }

        set
        {
            if (value != this.optionCommandValue)
            {
                this.optionCommandValue = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    public string Body
    {
        get
        {
            return this.bodyValue;
        }

        set
        {
            if (value != this.bodyValue)
            {
                this.bodyValue = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    public Color BodyColor
    {
        get
        {
            return this.bodyColorValue;
        }

        set
        {
            if (value != this.bodyColorValue)
            {
                this.bodyColorValue = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    public string LikeImageSource
    {
        get
        {
            return this.likeImageSource;
        }

        set
        {
            if (value != this.likeImageSource)
            {
                this.likeImageSource = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    public Command LikeClick
    {
        get
        {
            return this.likeCommandValue;
        }

        set
        {
            if (value != this.likeCommandValue)
            {
                this.likeCommandValue = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    public string Timestamp
    {
        get
        {
            return this.timestampValue;
        }

        set
        {
            if(value != this.timestampValue)
            {
                this.timestampValue = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    public Boolean ShowBanners
    {
        get
        {
            return this.showBannersValue;
        }

        set
        {
            if (value != this.showBannersValue)
            {
                this.showBannersValue = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I create a MessageObject using

```
MessageObject mo = MessageObject.CreateMessage(
                message.Id,
                new Command((sender) => ShowOptionActions(message.Id, message.Sender_Id, sender)),
                message.Body,
                message.Liked == 0 ? "like_icon.png" : "liked_icon.png",
                new Command((sender) => LikeMessageClick(message.Id, sender)),
                dateFormat.ToString("MMMM dd, yyyy HH:mm"));
```

my XAML is

```
<ContentPage.Content>
    <StackLayout BackgroundColor="#7ed6df">
        <local:PostListView x:Name="MessageView" HasUnevenRows="True" IsPullToRefreshEnabled="True" Refreshing="MessageView_Refreshing" SeparatorVisibility="None" BackgroundColor="#7ed6df">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <local:PostViewCell>
                        <StackLayout>
                            <StackLayout x:Name="MessageLayout" BackgroundColor="White" Margin="10, 10, 10, 10" Padding="10, 10, 15, 10">
                                <Image Source="options_icon.png" HeightRequest="18" HorizontalOptions="End" Margin="5, 0, 5, 0" IsVisible="{Binding ShowBanners}">
                                    <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                                        <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding OptionClick}" CommandParameter="{Binding .}"/>
                                    </Image.GestureRecognizers>
                                </Image>
                                <Label Text="{Binding Body}" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" TextColor="{Binding BodyColor}" FontSize="15" Margin="0, 10, 0, 10"/>
                                <StackLayout x:Name="MessageFooter" Orientation="Horizontal" IsVisible="{Binding ShowBanners}">
                                    <Image x:Name="LikeSource" Source="{Binding LikeImageSource}" HeightRequest="20" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" Margin="0, 0, 10, 0">
                                        <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                                            <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding LikeClick}" CommandParameter="{Binding .}"/>
                                        </Image.GestureRecognizers>
                                    </Image>
                                    <Label Text="{Binding Timestamp}" TextColor="Black" FontSize="10" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand"/>
                                </StackLayout>
                            </StackLayout>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </local:PostViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </local:PostListView>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

My full stack trace is [here](https://pastebin.com/fRxHsSET)

Edit:

I added a new TapGesture for a new item and it has the same issue.

Comment: not sure if this is the issue, but your XAML has a CommandParameter but your actual Command does not

Comment: @Jason I tried removing the CommandParameter, same result.

Comment: see if there is an InnerException value that gives more detail

Comment: There isn't allot of info here so its hard to see what the problem could be.
I would suggest changing this line:
`OptionClick = new Command((sender) => page.DisplayAlert("ok", "ok", "ok"))` to
`OptionClick = new Command(() => page.DisplayAlert("ok", "ok", "ok"))`

Comment: @ChristoNel The code still caused the error. :(

Comment: Can you show us the definition of `OptionClick` and the stacktrace of the exception? (not as comment, edit the question pls)

Comment: @Daniel it was worth a try.
Quick question though, where do you setup your BindingContext?

Comment: I added more code, I realled need to find the fix. @Sven-MichaelStübe

Comment: I added all my code. @ChristoNel

Comment: Did you look you android native code? What I'm seeing is that hes calling correctly, but something got wrong on the android renderer.

Comment: @AlanJonesRios I tried replacing them with the default example "local:PostListView" to "ListView" so it wouldn't use any of my android renderers, still happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't much information we get here, To get the real error try this answer from another Question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3838680/1752562).

If that does not work try commenting out your xaml section by section. error could be in `<local:PostViewCell>` for all we know.

and where is your ViewModel ? it needs a BindableBase

Comment: I posted all the code above. But it only occurs when OptionClick is being run.

Comment: I started getting _System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: < Timeout exceeded getting exception details >_ now

Answer (score 1):

Try verify your android native custom renderer, place some breakpoints there.

Comment: Could it be something in my android properties? https://imgur.com/a/bKd5V

Comment: Your properties are ok. Can you run again, wait until it break and hit the continue button on VS and get the log? Sometimes the real problem is only written after the break/crash.

Comment: It says "Your app has entered a break state, but there is no code to show because all threads were executing external code." and clicking continue makes it say "No compatible code running"

Comment: The stacktrace doesn't seem to point to where the error is https://pastebin.com/cvZcc2Rb

Answer (score 1):

For the command, try running the 'ShowOptionActions' method on the main thread. You can either do that within the `ShowOptionActions` method itself, or like so:

```
new Command((sender) =>
    Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => { 
        ShowOptionActions(message.Id, message.Sender_Id, sender));
    })
```